# Retrieve picture from access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm saving a picture in an access database, and everything is OK but when I want to retrieve it I can't.

This is my code to save the picture in database. I need code to retrieve it to a PictureBox in vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Try

        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "image file (*.jpg, *.bmp, *.png) | *.jpg; *.bmp; *.png| all files (*.*) | *.* "
         If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
             PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
             PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

         End If
     Catch ex As Exception

     End Try
 End Sub

 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
     Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

     Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)

     Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
     breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
     fsreader.Close()

     con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; data source = |datadirectory|\test.accdb;"
     con.Open()
     Dim sql As String
     sql = "insert into TS Values(" & TextBox1.Text & ",'" & imgbuffer.Length & "')"
     Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     cmd.Dispose()
     con.Close()
 End Sub
```

Comment: if you wrote this insert the update shouldn't be hard...start at Select from ........

Comment: Please learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Your code does not look like saving the image in the database, it ìnserts only `imgbuffer.Length` and `TextBox1.Text` (whatever that contains) into the table TS. But the content of imgbuffer is going nowhere.

Comment: TextBox1.text is the ID for the picture , and the imgbuffer insert into data base as(OLE Object), but i cant retrieve the picture from database :(

Comment: Maybe I am confused, or why can't I find any code in your example which does what you described? When the data is not written to the DB, I would not expect that it is possible to retrieve the data afterwards.

Comment: i don'n know , how i can save picture to database with openfiledialog and retrieve it .please if you can help me , thanks a lot :) @DocBrown

Comment: See here: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;316887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But I don't think that you're saving the Image in a Binary format, and even you have not put your last update on this query. So I assume you have saved the Image in a Binary form.
Let's take a look.

I assume that if you've saved the Image in "Long Binary data", then you have to call that Image by using the Image `ID`. Or, better, if you're using a Student's Number.
Now what you do here is simply make a `TextBox` (i.e. Textbox1). Then follow the code.

Open a Connection first then:

```
Try
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Image FROM Table WHERE Rollno ='" & textbox1.Text & "'", myconnection)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rollno", Textbox1.Text)
    Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

    myconnection.Close()
    command.Dispose()
    Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)'See in this picturebox1 you're showing the Image.
    '' NOTE: don't dispose the stream!!
Catch ex As Exception
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Label3.Text = "The Given Rollno has not found in the database"
    Return
End Try
```

Comment: I hope this will help you or It'll help those who are looking for this kinda query.Best of luck