# How to Show/Retrieve or Get the Image to PictureBox from Access Database?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub UpdatePicture()

    Dim str As String
    str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=UsersDB.accdb"
    cn = New OleDbConnection(str)
    cn.Open()

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    Dim arrimage() As Byte
    If (PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing) Then
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        arrimage = ms.GetBuffer
        ms.Close()
    End If

    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "UPDATE  Users set Picture = @img where StudentNumber " & TextBox1.Text & ""
        .Parameters.Add("@img", OleDbType.Binary).Value = IIf(PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing, arrimage, DBNull.Value)
        'con.Open()
        i = .ExecuteNonQuery()
        .Dispose()
        cn.Close()
        If (i > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Save Successs!")
        End If
    End With
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Can someone give me the code  to Show/Retrieve or Get the Image to my PictureBox1.Image from Access Database based on this code?

Comment: Please post code showing how you have attempted to solve your issue. StackOverflow is not a give you the code website. Please show effort and follow these suggestions when asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can write an image to a stream using eg `PictureBox1.Image.Save()` from which you can get bytes to store. To retrieve, read binary data into an image using `PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromXXX()` methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve picture from access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890646/retrieve-picture-from-access-database)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out, this is the solution:

```
Public Class Form

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\UsersDB.accdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("", con)
    Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim i As Integer

  Public Sub GetData()

        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable("Users")
        Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Users where StudentNumber='" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", con)
        rs.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count
        rs.Dispose()
        con.Close()

        If Val(Label1.Text) = 1 Then
            Dim i As Integer
            i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
            'Image
            Dim bytes As [Byte]() = (DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value)
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

        End If
  End Sub

End Class
```