# How to retrieve image from access to picturbox in vb. Net

Tags: vb.net

Im using the adodb type of coding in vb. Net and i need help to retrieve image to picturebox,

Is this right?

```
Picturebox.BackgroundImage = rs.Fields("picture").value
```

I got error in that code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
to see what and  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). 
if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve picture from access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890646/retrieve-picture-from-access-database)

Comment: The format used to store the image counts. It can be a `Package`, a OLE object, or binary data. If the latter, a MemoryStream is enough. If one of the packages formats, you have to remove the extra bytes, which are part of the package. One  way is to search for known image signatures inside the byte array (e.g., a JPEG Image always starts with `FF D8 FF` etc.). Otherwise, you could use the Packaging tools (avoid, IMO). This can be useful: [Reading and writing images to MS-Access 2007 and higher databases](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Reading-and-writing-to-MS-945a0615)

Answer (score 0):

This topic is already there [Retrieve Picture from Access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890646/retrieve-picture-from-access-database). It may help solving your problem.

Other method is to databound your picture box with database if your datatype in database is OLE Object.