# Insert & receive picture from ms access query db vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

so, I want to insert a picture to my ms-access DB and it works fine.

inserting code :

```
Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(GunaPictureBox1.Image)
bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
bytImage = ms.ToArray()
ms.Close()
Dim d As New DBConnect
d.Editdata(String.Format("INSERT INTO TeachersTable (TeacherFN, TeacherLN, [TeacherImage]) values('{0}','{1}','{2}')", GunaTextBox1.Text, GunaTextBox2.Text, bytImage))
```

display code :

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata(String.Format("SELECT [TeachersTable.TeacherImage] FROM TeachersTable where TeachersTable.ID= {0}", 1))
Dim EditTeacher As New EditTeacher
Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0)(1), Byte())
Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
EditTeacher.GunaPictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
EditTeacher.Show()
```

but now I want to display it on a picture box but when I execute the code its shows me an error said "Parameters is not valid" & I don't know where is the problem!

Comment: `dt.Rows(0)(1)` refers to `row(0)` & `column(1)`. You're fetching only one field (`Select TeacherImage FROM ...`), so it should be: `dt.Rows(0)(0)` ;)

Comment: Don't you don't get an exception in `DirectCast(dt.Rows(0)(1), Byte())`?

Comment: Did you debug the code? I'd wager not, given that you didn't even tell us where the exception occurred. You should have set a breakpoint at the top of the code, stepped through it line by line and examined the state before and after every step to see where and how the behaviour differed from your expectation. Even if you couldn't fix the issue yourself, you should be able to provide us with much more information. You need to ALWAYS debug before posting here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes after debugging i found the error in this line `EditTeacher.GunaPictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)` but im trying to solve this

Comment: That means that your `Stream` does not contain valid image data, which means that your `Byte` array doesn't contain valid image data. It appears that you're only getting one value from the database anyway, so I have to question why you're using a `DataTable` at all. This is a classic example of people trying to do the right thing by implementing a dedicated DAL but doing it badly. If you want one value you should get one value, which means calling `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: yep actually I use this query to get many values from ms access db.. also I have a question, in access what type of data should I use for image data: OLE Object or what? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve picture from access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890646/retrieve-picture-from-access-database)

Comment: What matters is that you need to use `OleDbType.LongVarBinary` as the command parameter type when you save a Bitmap's bytes, as in  `[OleDbCommand].Parameters.Add("@theImageParam", OleDbType.LongVarBinary).Value = [Your Byte array]`. In Access, you can set `OLE Object` as the field type. When you save the Image bytes, you'll see the Field content type change in `Long Binary Data`.

Comment: @Jimi so, to save image to ms access should i use OleDbType.LongVarBinary instead of a normal query ( like in my code ) ? i cant understand

Comment: When you build the query, use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add) to specify the data type of a field and add a Value, as shown in my previous comment (you **always** use Parameters to specify a Value to store, **never** pas a Value in the query directly - if you care about your data. Search the terms *SQL Injection*). You can find a lot of examples in SO.